# Put only one of my jobs per host, but OK to share with others

Tags: hpc, lsf

To mitigate a [lockfile problem](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/7776) until I find a proper solution, I would like to instruct LSF to put at most one of my jobs per host.  The [-x flag](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSETD4_9.1.3/lsf_command_ref/bsub.x.1.html) ensures my job has exclusive use of a host, but I do not need this; I am fine sharing with others.  I just don't want to share with myself.

How can I make sure that at most one of my jobs is run on a particular host, without asking for exclusive use of the entire host?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a general limit based on project.  Use PER_HOST=all, JOBS=1. Then attach your jobs to that project name.  The LSF admin needs to set this up.

Basically, add this to `lsb.resources`

```
Begin Limit
NAME = mylimit
PROJECTS = myproject
PER_HOST = all
JOBS=1
End Limit
```

Submit your jobs with `bsub -P myproject ...`.

**If you don't have LSF admin access**.  Then a slightly kludgy way to do the same thing is  to use the [host exclude feature](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSWRJV_10.1.0/lsf_admin/job_requeue_user_config.html). `bsub -Q "EXCLUDE(55)" ...` When your job starts, if another job of the same type is running, exit with code 55. Then LSF will requeue the job and add that host to a job specific black list. The exit code can be something else other than 55, but avoid using exit codes with [special meaning to the shell](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/exitcodes.html).

Comment: Can I do that as an ordinary user?  I have no administration rights.

Comment: An ordinary user cannot configure limits.  A option for an ordinary user is to use the [host exclude feature](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSWRJV_10.1.0/lsf_admin/job_requeue_user_config.html). (`bsub -Q "EXCLUDE(55)" ...`).  Its a bit kludgy, but will work.  When your job starts, if another job of the same type is running, exit with code 55. Then LSF will requeue the job and add that host to a job specific black list. The exit code can be something else other than 55, but avoid using exit codes with [special meaning](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/exitcodes.html) to the shell.